# Return all cache records, delete caches with prefixed keys

Tags: plugin-development, cache

Does `craft()->cache->` have a way of returning all the cache records? 
I need to delete some caches, but only if the key begins with a certain prefix, “`ranking__getAthletePoints_`”. I won’t know the numbers following in the key names. If I could grab all of them, I assume I could check against the key names with something like `startsWith()` and delete the correct caches that way.

Very much out of my element with php & plugin development! Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not without some brute-force cracking.

The keys you pass into [CFileCache's](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CFileCache) [set](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CCache#set-detail) and [get](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CCache#get-detail) methods are an md5 hash of your key prepended with your Craft installation's [appId](https://craftcms.com/docs/config-settings#appId) (which by default is a randomly generated string).

So with a key of `testKey`, that could end up as a value of `3f8b3c45a9c6f395d02b930f18910a92`.  For CFileCache, that value ends up being the file name of the cache file and gets put in `craft/storage/runtime/cache/3f8b3c45a9c6f395d02b930f18910a92.bin`.

Later, when you call get and pass in the key of `testKey`, it goes through the same process and checks to see if a file named `3f8b3c45a9c6f395d02b930f18910a92.bin` exists.  If it does, it knows there is a match.

As you can see, there's no way to find that match without knowing the key ahead of time (unless you brute-force cracked md5, which is doable, but probably not practical for your use-case).

Comment: Well yeah, "brute-force crack" is my middle name ;) ... Alright, thanks for the answer Brad. I'll have to rethink ways to go about my plugin.